# 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dotnetnuke

I am very new in DNN and using very first time; I have an application developed in DotNetNuke which I need to deploy on server. Server has **IIS6** and application has **DotNetNuke 6.2.01610**

After deploying site, I get error as `404 - File or directory not found`; There is already one DNN application deployed on same server with different domain and it works fine. I am trying to deploy that same code but my application gives error. It never hits to my login page.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you? We don't have access to your server, so we have no way of knowing what you've done wrong.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Besides, this should rather be moved to ServerFault...

Comment: I have a site deployed with different Domain but works fine; and i added same code with my domain name but my site fails; what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check portal alias table. Maybe it is still referring the old site